# How i generate mongoid.yml file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

When i run this command `"rails g mongoid:config"`
then show this error message

```
"Could not find generator mongoid:config"
```

How I can fix this issue? please help me...

I have added `gem "mongoid"` and `gem "rspec"` in my GemFile

Comment: DId u run `bundle install` ?

Comment: yes, i run this command

Comment: Thanks @Debadatt for correction in my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit the GemFile as

```
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
```

then run `bundle install`